# Separating javascript code from jsp page in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jsp, vue.js, requirejs

I have a Spring MVC application and right now the javascript code is embedded within the jsp pages. I know this is not a good design as there is no segregation. I am trying to separate jsp and javascript code for which I plan to use either of the two oprtions:

`1. Use define and require to externalize the javascript functions`

`2. Use either Vue.js or Handlebars` (*I tried doing this but I am not able to integrate vue as part of grunt build and it looks there would be a lot of additional work required to make the changes*).

I am inclining more towards the first option but I am not quite sure

> How do I use define and require with Jsp pages?

Can someone please provide some sort of documentation(specific to Javascript with Jsp) or example that I can use as a launchpad.

Comment: _How do I use define and require with Jsp pages?_ - you don't; you place `<script>` tags in your JSP that references your JavaScript file.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-vue